# One package.json for a client + server React project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app, package.json

Right now, I have a project structure that looks like this:

```
- /client
    - create react app files
    - package.json
- /server
    - server files
- package.json
```

So there's a client folder, which contains an independent CRA install, and a server folder, which contains all the server files. This could be Express, or Hapi, or whatever, doesn't really matter.

Right now with this setup, I have to maintain a package.json inside the client folder for all the client things, as I don't know a way to call `react-scripts start` from outside the install of a CRA.

I'd prefer to have a single install, so for CI I wouldn't have to `npm ci` in two places and maintain two `node_modules`, etc.

Is there any way to have CRA know to install everything for a subdirectory, or would I just have to make a custom Webpack setup?

Comment: This may not be a direct solution to what you're looking for, but `concurrently` may be able to at least eliminate the need of having to open two terminal windows. [Concurrently Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

Comment: Yeah, I decided to use Webpack and make a custom setup with concurrently instead of using CRA.